# How to return values from a void function?

Tags: c++

Here is parts of my program and I need to return the value of length back to main
Any help?

```
void getLength(double length)
{
cout << "Enter the length: ";
cin >> length;
if (length < INVAL){
    cout << "Do not accept negative values for length. Try again: ";
    cin >> length;
}
return length;
}
....
int main()
{
double length = 0;
double width = 0;
double area = 0;

getLength(length);
getWidth(width);
calcArea(length, width, area);
printData(length, width, area);
}
```

Comment: a) Not void, b) References, c) Pointer ...

Comment: why don't you change the return type from `void` to `int`?

Comment: Will that return the value?

Comment: Make length a reference. `void getLength (double & length) `

Comment: `return length;` returns the value. But `void` as a return type means the function doesn't return anything. There's a contradiction there, and the compiler tells you as much.

Comment: So void should be double or int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the parameter length a reference. `void getLength (double & length)` and delete the return. After calling the function the passed parameter has the value assigned to it in the function.

Comment: I would argue this is less clear than using a return value. It is natural for functions to take input parameters and output a return value.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a locked room mystery?

Easiest way is to change it from a void to a double. Alternatively you could have the function modify a public variable in main.

Do you need to keep it a void?

Comment: No I don't.  I just need to get the length inside that function and return it to main

Comment: Just change it from void to double then.